# Unable to update textarea value with formatted text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JS function that takes a block of text pasted inside textarea, removes line breaks but keeps paragraph breaks, and updates the text inside that textarea before I submit a form.

I have attempted to do it this way:

```
<textarea name="sum" id="sum" onpaste="frmt()"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
function frmt() {
    const tar = document.getElementById("sum");
    const reg = /[\r\n](?![\r\n])/g;        
    const str = tar.value;  
    tar.innerHTML = str.replace(reg, "");
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the `frmt` function? What is the problem? Inline event handlers like `onpaste` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: `<textarea>` values should be set via `.value`, not `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea name="sum" id="sum"></textarea>

<script>
  const sum = document.getElementById('sum');

  sum.addEventListener('paste', () =>
    setTimeout(
      () => (sum.value = sum.value.replace(/[\r\n](?![\r\n])/g, '')),
      0
    )
  );
</script>
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event*

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea>` is not supported `.innerHTML` so you need to set values through `.value` and you can use `oninput` event.

**This event occurs when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.**

*Helpful links:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

```js
function frmt(id){    
    const tar = document.getElementById(id);
    const reg = /[\r\n](?![\r\n])/g;
    const str = tar.value;
    tar.value = str.replace(reg, "")
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 95%;
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="sum" id="sum" oninput="frmt('sum')"></textarea>
```